# Android stay log in

Tags: android, authentication, logout

I would like to have the user stay log in even when app is killed and reopened after logging in once.

I have 
login java page, 
a click and logout function in another page.

How do I use sharedpreferences to get the result I wanted?

As far as I know, sharedpreferences is only usable within one java page.

.

.

Thanks for any suggestions or sample will be nice.

Comment: please understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Answer (score 0):

Try this-
when u login set sharedpreference value

eg `editor.putBoolean("key_name1", true);`

on clicking logout button make it false

eg `editor.putBoolean("key_name1", false);`

everytime your launch activity loads (you start your app) check the value of the sharedpreference

if the value is true user is logged in otherwise logged out